# Transpose of the differentiation operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Please help me write down a step by step solution to the following problem

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space of all polynomial functions over the field of real numbers which have degree at most $n$ i.e. functions of the form $$f(x)=c_0+c_1x+\dots + c_nx^n$$  Let $D$ be the differentiation operator on $V$.Find a basis for the null space of the transpose operator $D^t$.

Comment: Show us your work so far.

Comment: The null space of the transpose of an operator is the annihilator of its image. So compute the image of $D$ and find all elements inthe dual space which vanish there.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840766/the-kernel-of-the-transpose-of-the-differentiation-operator-solution-check?rq=1) is a related post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We represent a polynomial of the form $f(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + \cdots + c_n x^n$ by the $n+1$ dimensional vector $(c_0,c_1,\cdots,c_n)^T$ and we first wish to find an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$-dimensional matrix $M$ to represent the differentiation operator $D$. Observing that $f'(x) = c_1 + 2 c_2 x + \cdots + n c_n x^{n-1}$, we can represent $f(x)$ by

$$D  ((c_0,c_1,\cdots,c_n)^T) = (c_1,2c_2,\cdots,n c_n,0)^T$$

And we can check that the matrix corresponding to this linear transformation has the form $$M = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0  & 0 &\cdots & 0 & n \\ 0 & 0& \cdots & 0  & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

(i.e. we have $1,2,\cdots,n$ on the superdiagonal of the matrix). We see that the transpose of this matrix is $$M^T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & n & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

and then we can see by inspection that any vector of the form $(0,\cdots,0,a)$ will be in the nullspace of $M^T$, so any vector of that form will give us the desired basis (we know that the nullspace of our $(n+1)\times(n+1)$-dimensional matrix will be 1-dimensional because our matrix has rank $n$).

In terms of polynomials of degree $n$, it is polynomials of the form $g(x) = c_n x^n$ which form the nullspace of the transpose of the differentiation operator.

Comment: I might be wrong, but looking at this it seems to suggest the transpose of the derivative is an integral???

Comment: @ivbc - almost, but the subdiagonal matrices need to be inverted. M^T here has entries 1,2,...,n, but for an integral you'd want entries 1,1/2,1/3,...,1/n.  Also the polynomial order grows by one when integrating, so you'd actually need to increase the size of the matrix and add an entry for 1/(n+1).

Comment: @KevinHolt If the operation of the derivative matrix times the integral matrix isn't equal to the identity, Is it correct to describe in matrix form as show above?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Is it correct to use a matrix to describe the integral's effect on the coefficients of a polynomial?  Sure, but I think it must be non-square.  If V(n) is the space of n-order polynomials (with n+1 coefficients), then the integrals are in space V(n+1), using (n+2) coefficients.  So the integral matrix would be rectangular, of size (n+2)x(n+1).  Side-note, I would probably write the derivative as an (n)x(n+1) matrix, but no harm to write it as an (n+1)x(n+1) matrix with an all-zero last row, as in the answer above.