# The kernel of the transpose of the differentiation operator - Solution check

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I tried to solve the following problem and I'd like some feedback on my solution:

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $V$ be $P_n(\Bbb R)$the space of all polynomials functions over the field of the real numbers which have degree at most $n$. Let $D$ be the differentiation operator on $V$. Find a basis for the null space of the transpose operator $D^t$.

Here's my solution:

Since $Ker\ D^T = (Im \ D)^0$, and $ImD=P_{n-1}(\Bbb R)$ we have $Ker\ D^t=(P_{n-1}(\Bbb R))^0$.
But since $dim\ P_n(\Bbb R)=dim\ P_{n-1}(\Bbb R)+dim\ (P_{n-1}(\Bbb R))^0$, it follows that $dim\ (P_{n-1}(\Bbb R))^0=1$.

Consider now the following linear functional over $P_n(\Bbb R)$:

$f:\ P_n(\Bbb R)\rightarrow \Bbb R$

$a_o+...+a_nx^n\mapsto a_n$

This linear operator annihilates $P_{n-1}(\Bbb R)$ (viewed as a subspace of $P_n(\Bbb R)$). Since its nonzero and $dim\ (P_{n-1}(\Bbb R))^0=1$, we have that {$\ f$} is a basis for $(P_{n-1}(\Bbb R))^0 = Ker\ D^t$

Comment: remark that $P_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})^0=\mathbb{R} x^n$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614581/transpose-of-the-differentiation-operator) is a related post.